# Django: How to sort on manytomany field in Admin Site?

Tags: django

I have below django admin site. The fields Industries and Nationalities are manytomany fields in Person model.
Based on Person model below admin page is designed.
The name, profession and date of birth fields can be sort by default. However Industries and Nationalities can't be sorted. Is there any way that we can enable sorting on manytomany fields as well?

[image]

After applying the solution mentioned in the comment, I can see the sorting is activated however after sorting the data looks in bad order.
Please check the Industries column in below screen shot.

Is there any way to correct that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If an element of list_display represents a certain database field, you can indicate this fact by setting the admin_order_field attribute of the item.

For example

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['display_name', 'profession', 'industries', 'nationalites', 'date_of_birth']
    nationalites.admin_order_field = 'nationalites__name'
    industries.admin_order_field = 'industries__name'
```

more information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: I am seeing the order is not correct. I have attached the screen shot above. Is there any way to correct it?

Comment: Сould you please provide the code of the models so i can reproduce the problem